Is this possible in Django ORM? I want to query on reverse foreign key relation ship. I need quite a few queries from the database
What I have?
I have models as below.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


Basically I want to track a price of a product.
Each product has one current price and it may have previous price history.
I need quite a few things.
What I need?
I need products with prices but ordered by price.
What I did?
I did the following thing.
queryset = Product.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("price_set", queryset=Price.objects.all())
)
queryset = queryset.order_by("price__amount")

Is this correct? Or there is a more efficient way of doing this?
What I need?
I need to sort products by number of price changes.
For example, if product A's price is changed 5 times in last 10 days, and product B's price is changed 6 times in last 10 days, then product B should be first and product A should be second in the queryset?
I have no idea how to do this.
Please help me out with these two questions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
What I tried is as above.

You can do this by adding the related price changes within the specified time frame and then sort the queryset based on this count.
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from datetime import timedelta


time_frame = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=10)


queryset = Product.objects.annotate(
    price_changes_count=Count(
        "price",
        filter=Q(price__timestamp__gte=time_frame)
    )
)


queryset = queryset.order_by("-price_changes_count")

